# MySQL statement in Python: Variables don't work

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a problem with MySQL and Python's MySQLdb when I try to INSERT more than one variable.

I have a table wordurl with three fields. The first one is an auto_increment ID, second and third should hold the values. Second and third fields are named word_id and url_id.

This is the code.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES (%s, %s)", (word_temp_id, url_temp_id))
```

When I try to INSERT only one value the code works, two not.

Error message:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),), (('2',),))' at line 1")
```

I also tried it with tripple ticks around the statement, the variables with and without bracket, without the field names and with the first id field included. I also tried with C-style-printf-stuff % (which isn't clever!). Nothing worked.

And you, glorious people on stackoverflow, you are my last hope :)

MySQL-Server is 5.5.9 on FreeBSD 8.2. Python version is 2.7:82508 on OSX Lion

Thanks in advance!

Steffen

UPDATE: I use cursor.fetchall() and cursor.fetchone() to get the IDs. Maybe this information is important.

Comment: its seems that url_temp_id is empty

Comment: No, it isn't. If I comment out the statement and replace it with print it says `(((233L,),), ((3L,),))` There are two values. But there are too much bracket, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your update:

AFAIK:
fetchall() returns a tuple with tuples inside. Those tuples inside are what you would get from fetchone(). You can image it like

```
fetchall() = (fetchone(), fetchtwo(), ...)
```

And fetchone also returns a tuple which has the actual variable values. This is why you can't simply insert the return value of fetchall().

Just to clarify: the insert statement you pasted, look like this when you fill in the value for max_price:

```
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast WHERE price < %s""", (5,))
```

so the first %s is replaced with the first element of the tuple (5). Your insert statement looks like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES (%s, %s)", (((233L,),), ((3L,),)))
```

I can't make it more clear.

Comment: I tried that, too. It does not work. If I print them, it looks like this `(((233L,),), ((3L,),))` There is a difference in the bracket and a comma. Maybe this is the error?

Comment: what are all those brackets doing there? o.O How did you print them?

Comment: Like this `print(word_temp_id, url_temp_id)`

Comment: You can't insert those variables with all those brackets. Where do you define them? Note that fetchone() returns a tuple of tuples afaik. Check where you assign values to those variables and print out what you get from fetchone() or whatever.

Comment: I found in the MySQLdb User's Guide that we need a tuple here like `c=db.cursor()
max_price=5
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
          WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
`

Comment: Yes, but you have two of such tuples you want to insert. But still you can insert them with `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (word_temp_id, url_temp_id))` if your word_temp_id and url_temp_id are no tuples but real values.

Comment: What you were pasting "those with eggs" works fine, becouse price is usually an int value. Remember, that %s pastes exactly the string itself. If you try to use `"%s foo" % 'spam'`, the result will be `"foo spam"`, not `"'foo' spam"`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. For example this pice of code `cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO word (word) VALUE (%s)''', (element))
                cursor.execute('''SELECT wordid FROM word WHERE word = (%s)''', (element))
                word_temp_id = cursor.fetchall()
                
                word_temp_id = cursor.fetchall()` When I do a `print(len(word_temp_id))` it says `0` So there is no value but there should be one because I just added a new `element`. Right?

Comment: (I came to `len` because I tried `temp = word_temp_id[0]` and it was out of range)

Comment: It works now! I take the value from inside the tuple, put it into another temp variable and hand it over to the MySQL statement. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" %(word_temp_id, url_temp_id))`

It depends on what variables you're trying to insert, but on strings this is needed.

Notice the difference:

```
>>> word_temp_id = "bla1"
>>> url_temp_id = "bla2"
>>> query = "INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES (%s, %s)" %(word_temp_id, url_temp_id)
>>> print query
INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES (bla1, bla2)
>>> query = "INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" %(word_temp_id, url_temp_id)
>>> print query
INSERT INTO wordurl (word_id, url_id) VALUES ('bla1', 'bla2')
```

Comment: I gave it a try but it is still not working. The Error is still the same. I think I have a tuple error here

Comment: What exactly are you trying to insert? Can you paste an example of word_tem_id and url_temp_id? Provided with their type?

Comment: I try to insert an integer (in a tupel?) I fetch via `cursor.fetchall()`. If I print it it looks like `(((233L,),), ((3L,),))`

Comment: Take a look at how example fetchall looks like:
    `query = "select user, timeborders_ptr_id from db 
    cursor.execute( query )
    timeborders = cursor.fetchall()
    for tuple in timeborders:
        user = tuple[0]
        timeborder = tuple[1]`

The fetchall result will always has a form of (((user1,), (data1,)), ((user2,), (data2,)))

Comment: Yes, thanks. I got it. I changed to fetchone(), take the values from inside the tuple and write them into the statement.